# Trello webhook limits

Tags: webhooks, trello

I'm creating an app for a group of people that have board for each working person. It's around 50 boards together, and what comes to my mind is a question, does trello webhooks have any limits?

I couldn't find any information about the amount of webhooks that are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

​No, there is not. [Here](https://help.trello.com/article/838-api-rate-limits) is information about webhooks limits that says directly:

> There is no limit to the number of webhooks you can set up in Trello

However here on [TrelloDev limits](https://developers.trello.com/docs/limits):

> In addition to limiting the number of different types of objects that can exist on a board or card, we disallow creating new webhooks on objects that have exceeded their limits. 
>   Attempting to create a webhook on an object that has exceeded its limits will result in the following error message: HTTP/1.1 500 Model exceeds limits

That, in my humble opinion, simply indicates that as long as other objects limits are not exceeded, there is no limit for webhooks, therefore you should just worry about other elements and as long as they will be kept under the limit everything will be just fine.

Comment: My bad, i have read the api limits section but not the staying under limit one... Thanks for your answer.